# Trying to understand vsftpd log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vsftpd

I'm currently learning Linux and using FTP however I can't make sense of the log file any help would be appreciated.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log# cat vsftpd.log
Mon Jan 18 06:39:48 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:40:12 2021 [pid 1] [ppolly] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:42:46 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:43:03 2021 [pid 1] [ppolly] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:43:13 2021 [pid 3] [ppolly] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "192.168.20.105", "/home/ppolly/list.txt", 284 bytes, 81.91Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 18 07:10:25 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 07:10:34 2021 [pid 1] [fred] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:12:35 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:12:57 2021 [pid 1] [admin] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:03 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:13 2021 [pid 1] [root] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:20 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:35 2021 [pid 1] [administrator] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:52 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:07 2021 [pid 1] [ftpadmin] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:16 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:26 2021 [pid 1] [adminftp] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:59 2021 [pid 1] [pete] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
```

Comment: First off, welcome to Linux! Secondly, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Serverfault. I hate to be the guy to say read the manual, but in this case it might be the best thing to read the manual. It'll help you learn about the system, and you'll be better able to interpret what the computer is trying to tell you. This log snippet is just a list of login attempts.

Comment: Please specify what it is that you dont understand as well.